# Неправильно выводятся числа из файла в массив

Tags: c++, массивы, файлы

Мне нужно вывести числа записанные в файле `input_data.txt` в массив, но вместо ожидаемого массива в виде

```
11  5 7
 3  4 6
18 15 9
```

получаю вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**main.cpp:**

````
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream input_data;
    input_data.open("input_data.txt");

    if (!input_data.is_open()) {
        cout << "Error while opening file";
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    // int SIZE = input_data.gcount();

    int count = 0;

    while (!input_data.eof()) {
        char ch;
        while (input_data >> ch)
            count++;
    }

    int SIZE = sqrt(count);
    double** arr = new double* [SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        arr[i] = new double[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            input_data >> arr[i][j];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        cout << "\n";
    }

    double max;

    max = (arr[0][0] > arr[1][0]) ? arr[0][0] : arr[1][0];
    max = (arr[0][0] > arr[2][0]) ? arr[0][0] : arr[2][0];
    max = (arr[1][0] > arr[2][0]) ? arr[1][0] : arr[2][0];

    ofstream output_data;
    output_data.open("output_data.txt");

    if (!output_data.is_open()) {
        cout << "Error while opening file";
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
                output_data << setprecision(3) << fixed << arr[i][j] / max << " ";
            }
            output_data << endl;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        delete[] arr[i];
    delete[] arr;

    input_data.close();
    output_data.close();
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Два замечания... Выведите перед `int SIZE = sqrt(count);` на экран значение `count` и посмотрите на него. И второе. У вас уже дочитан файл до конца. И вы опять пытаетесь из него читать. Откуда? Конец файла достигнут, состояние файла — `eof`, очередное чтение просто не выполняется...

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на вот этот Ваш код:

```
while (!input_data.eof()) {
    char ch;
    while (input_data >> ch)
        count++;
}
```

Вы дочитали файл до конца. Ему система выставила флаг, что он уже прочитан.
А Вы после этого пытаетесь из него выжать (прочитать) что-то еще. Что же Вы сможете прочитать? - разве что ошибки оператора ввода.

Как исправить? Во-первых, нужно "перемотать" файл на начало с помощью команды типа `input_data.seekg(0)`. Во-вторых, вам нужно сбросить флаг достижения конца файла: `input_data.clear()`. И только после этого можно пытаться читать файл заново. (как вариант - можно закрыть и потом снова открыть файл, но "это грубо и не по-европейски" (c))

Все это было бы хорошо, но даже тогда, Вы получите снова ошибку из-за того, что Вы неверно определяете необходимый размер массивов `SIZE`. Вы его пытаетесь вычислить через размер файла? А кто сказал, что все числа будут одноразрядные? И как тут учесть пробелы - они же тоже занимают место в файле? В приведенном цикле Вам нужно бы считывать не в переменную типа `char`, а считать, сколько раз удастся прочитать данные того типа, из которого у Вас состоит массив (`double`).

Answer (score 0):

В первую очередь вам необходимо ознакомиться с тем, как вообще работают потоки ввода/вывода в c++. Общая их характеристика - флаги состояния. Можно почитать общую документацию по `basic_ifstream` [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream). В случае, если чтение из файла может продолжаться, по умолчанию стоит флаг `goodbit`. Если встречается какая-то ошибка, из-за которой невозможен дальнейший ввод/вывод, либо требуется вмешательство пользователя, то выставляются флаги ошибки `eof`, `badbit` и другие в зависимости от типа ошибки.

В вашем случае в вот этом отрезке кода вы считываете весь файл посимвольно, вплоть до конца файла:

```
while (!input_data.eof()) {
    char ch;
    while (input_data >> ch)
        count++;
}
```

Вполне логично предположить, что когда встречается конец файла, выставляется флаг `eof`, что делает дальнейший ввод/вывод невозможным (и это причина по которой `input_data.eof()` возвращает `true`). Далее вы пытаетесь заполнить массив, пытаясь снова вывести что-то из файла, но выводить уже нечего - конец файла достигнут.

Для решения проблемы нужно сделать две вещи:

1. Сбросить флаги ошибок
2. Вернуть курсор в начало файла, либо пересоздать соединение с ним (первый вариант предпочтительнее по очевидным причинам)

Сброс `eof` флага осуществляется при помощи функции `basic_ifstream::clear()`. Почитать конкретно о функции можно [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof).

Смена же позиции курсора достигается функцией [basic_ifstream::seekg](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg). В вашем случае нужно прописать `input_data.seekg(0)`.

Кроме того, я настоятельно рекомендую заменить динамический массив на, например, `std::string` или `std::vector` заполнять его внутри `while`, примерно так:

```
// Код на идеальность не претендует
// Работоспособность не проверял

std::string data;

while (!input_data.eof()) {
    char ch;
    while (input_data >> ch)
        count++;
        data.push_back(ch);
}
```